# Count repeats in a list and store them as a multiple

Tags: r, list

I have a list, which looks like this (the ID is the name of each element in the list and the scores are the values).
[image]

The problem is some of the elements contain duplicate values. For example: for ID = 8, the scores are: 1, 1, 2, 4.

I want to be able to count if there are any repeats and store the number of repeats. In this case: 1x2, 2, 4.

I have tried:

```
str_count(patient.variants[[8]], "1")
```

But this just returns:
1, 1, 0, 0.

###### Data for Example

```r
list("1" = c("1", "2", "2"), "2" = c("1", "1", "2", "3"), "3" = c("1", "1", "2", "2"))
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible data, or just copy/paste the output of `dput(patient.variants)`.

Comment: Its confidential data so I cant, and had to provide something similar. @DarrenTsai

Comment: Can you post your data in reproducible format? It is not clear what format `Scores` is in, and your "list" doesn't appear to be a typical R `list` either. This is not being pedantic - it is necessary to give you the correct solution.

Comment: If the data is confidential, can you please post some dummy data that is in the same format and gives the same error when you run the same code?

Comment: @AllanCameron Please see edit! Does that help? Thanks :)

Comment: @DarrenTsai I do apologise. Please can you see my edit. I have created a list called "hey" which represents the same.

Comment: Fine! Please copy/paste the output of `dput(hey)` to your question, and delete the image.

Comment: @DarrenTsai list(`1` = c("1", "2", "2"), `2` = c("1", "1", "2", "3"), `3` = c("1", 
"1", "2", "2"))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```r
lapply(lst, \(x) {
  tab <- table(x)
  unname(ifelse(tab > 1, paste(names(tab), tab, sep = "x"), names(tab)))
})

# $`1`
# [1] "1"   "2x2"
# 
# $`2`
# [1] "1x2" "2"   "3"  
# 
# $`3`
# [1] "1x2" "2x2"
```

---

###### Data

```r
lst <- list("1" = c("1", "2", "2"),
            "2" = c("1", "1", "2", "3"),
            "3" = c("1", "1", "2", "2"))
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `tapply`

```
lapply(lst1, \(x) unname(tapply(x, x, FUN = function(x) 
   if(length(x) > 1) paste(x[1], length(x), sep = "X") else x)))
$`1`
[1] "1"   "2X2"

$`2`
[1] "1X2" "2"   "3"  

$`3`
[1] "1X2" "2X2"
```